# Update DataLabels position on Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, position, axis

when I use dataLabel.translate command to update DataLabels position is working fine, but if I use a yAxis[i].update command, Highcharts is not Moving anymore any DataLabels.

If you pick Update data, Data Labels do NOT move, otherwise they move correctly.
[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/carolo/t04evhg7/7/)

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type:'column',        
    events:
    {
        load: function(){
            for(var j = 0; j < this.series.length; j++) {
                for(var i = 0; i < this.series[j].data.length; i++) {
                    var d = this.series[j].data[i];
                    d.dataLabel.translate(d.dataLabel.x, d.dataLabel.y-50);
                }
            }
        }
    }        
  },
  plotOptions: { series: {dataLabels: {enabled: true} } },    
  xAxis: {categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr']},    
  yAxis: {max: 100, min:0},    
  series: [{data: [60, 70, 45, 85]}]} , function(chart){
if(confirm('Update on YAxis?'))
{
  chart.yAxis[0].update({
      max: 500,
      min: 50,
      tickInterval: 50
  });
}});
```

Any ideas how can I still updating Yaxis Data and changing DataLabels positions?

Comment: Hi, check this demo with set timeout http://jsfiddle.net/a5enfkpo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If change the event from `load` to `render`, function from `translate` to `attr` and `d.dataLabel.y` to `d.dataLabel.alignAttr.y` the code will work:

```
    events: {
      render: function() {
        for (var j = 0; j < this.series.length; j++) {
          for (var i = 0; i < this.series[j].data.length; i++) {
            var d = this.series[j].data[i];
            d.dataLabel.attr({
              y: d.dataLabel.alignAttr.y - 50
            });
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/LL4z4eL5/

By the way, an easier way of doing the same thing is by using `dataLabels.y` property: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tpor20xa/

Comment: You just made my day